# Column search/comparison

Tags: vba

```
Sub compare()
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("A1:Z6")
Dim R As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    If Arr(R, 1) = Arr(R, 4) And Arr(R, 2) = Arr(R, 5) Then
        Arr(R, 3) = Arr(R, 6)
    End If 
Next R
Range("A1:Z6") = Arr
End Sub
```

The above code compares 2 columns to see if they are equal and 2 other columns to see if they are also equal at the same time. Then if those conditions are met it copies the value of a cell to another location.
The issue is that I am only comparing information in row one with other information in row one. What I need to do is compare the information from two cells in row one with the next two cells in rows 1,2,3... I have made a picture to better describe what I need. I need more loops clearly.

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/obf2w9o21/vba.png]

Thank you in advance to anyone who is willing to help!

Comment: This can be done with a formula.  Is VBA a necessity?

Comment: The formula in C1 is `IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(A1 & "|" & B1,$D:$D & "|" & $E:$E,0)),"")` and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

The code is based on your picture. Let me know

```
  Sub test()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastrow2 As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To Lastrow

            For j = 1 To Lastrow2

            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("D" & j).Value And Range("B" & i).Value = Range("E" & j).Value Then

                     Range("C" & i).Value = Range("F" & j).Value
            End If

        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```